# Wget etiquette?

Tags: wget

In my college, students sign up for classes online. It is a large university so people add and drop classes frequently. I made a simple script to alert me when people drop classes that I want to add. The program runs a loop that calls *wget* on the webpage where my class sits, waits 5 seconds, calls *wget* again, and then uses *diff* to compare the two files created. If *diff* finds a difference in the files *wget* creates, my script emails me a notification. I can then view the notification on my phone, and run to a computer. What I need to know is will my university ban me for this extra traffic. I looked at the terms of service for the website,  http://my.sa.ucsb.edu/home/TermsOfUse.aspx and found nothing saying my script is illegal. However I am still pretty worried.

Comment: We have no way of knowing whether your university will get mad.

Comment: Every 5 seconds? What university could possibly have this level of class churn?

Comment: take the CS courses and ace them, hack the uni's monitoring software...Voila! (btw I'm joking)

Comment: Internal traffic like that usually won't raise any red flags, but you should really change your delay to something more reasonable, like 15-30 minutes.

Comment: By the way, it is better to hash the files and compare the hashes rather than `diff` -ing.

Comment: I don't need to check it every five seconds, but if I wait too long for the refresh it logs me out. And logging back in requires manual intervention.

Comment: 5 seconds is overkill. Their system won't log you out after a few seconds. Set it to 5 minutes or something.

Answer (score 2):

What's the difference between your script and just sitting on the web page with a browser, hitting refresh every 5 seconds? I don't see why it should be a problem. Why don't you have it check like every 12 hours though? Do you really need to check every 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Do whatever you want!  Query your university's web site every 10 ms each on a farm of thousands of computers if needed!  Nothing bad* will come out of it, promise.

`*` for varying values of bad.

Answer (score 0):

It's a difficult one, however when ever I do wget's I judge them based on the environment at hand.

Here are the settings I usually use:

- -nc
- -nH
- -w 2

On some (rare) occasions, I might bump the wait timer to 5 seconds.